# Bootstrap 3 Alternative hover colour for specific row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a class called 'table-green-hover' which when set on a table makes it so that the hover colour is LightGreen instead of the usual bootstrap colour

```
.table-green-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td, 
.table-green-hover > tbody > tr:hover > th { background-color: LightGreen; }
```

However for 2 specific rows in my table (with a class of 'logout-hover') I want those to be a completely different colour, I thought of doing it as

```
.logout-hover > tr:hover > td { background-color: LightBlue; }
```

Though it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all, when I hover over those 2 specific rows they still show with the LightGreen.

Comment: can you create a demo/ provide all the related code?

Comment: Are both `table-green-hover `and `logout-hover` classes applied to the same `table`? Or is `logout-hover` class applied to the `tr` elements? Please show us your HTML.

Comment: table-green-hover is on the table element itself, logout-hover is on the specific tr element

Comment: example: http://www.bootply.com/0jErIpZxfK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit based on OP's comment:

```
.table-green-hover tr.logout-hover:hover > td { background-color: LightBlue; }
```

---

Old answer:

```
.logout-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td { background-color: LightBlue; }
```

The reason is because 
`.table-green-hover > tbody > tr:hover > th` (1 class, 3 elements) is *more specific* than `.logout-hover > tr:hover > td` (1 class, 2 elements), and thus got higher priority.

Comment: The OP said it still show LightGreen, which is the color mentioned above, so I can be quite sure the table has both classes.

Comment: table-green-hover is on the table element itself, logout-hover is on the specific tr element

Comment: Same issue. Have created a bootply which shows the problem: http://www.bootply.com/0jErIpZxfK

Comment: Actually, fumble fingers, I had an extra '.' after the 'tr', your one worked perfectly, thankyou for that.